# How to access the mysql table field schema description column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to obtain or query the description column of the table schema?

Currently:

```
  si_table_name = params[:rid]
  @si_field_names = Array.new      
  si_cols = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns(si_table_name, "#{name} Columns")
  si_cols.each do |c|
    @si_field_names << "#{c.name}:#{c.type}"  <---------------
  end
```

Goal: (this example doesn't work... looking for the correct way to query this)

```
  si_table_name = params[:rid]
  @si_field_names = Array.new      
  si_cols = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.columns(si_table_name, "#{name} Columns")
  si_cols.each do |c|
    @si_field_names << "#{c.name}:#{c.type}:#{c.description}" <---------------
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'description'.

In any case, the table metadata can be queried using the information schema.

See
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html

and in particular the table information_schema.columns, column COLUMN_COMMENT.